# no sound except LiveChat headphones; controllers say "access denied"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

No sound from either system speakers or external speakers.  When I plug in headphones, they work.  This just happended -- I've been installing new versions of LibreOffice, OnlyOffice.  I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a new Lenovo computer.

When I run `lspci -v` it shows many controllers with "access denied".  What does this mean, and how do I correct it, if I need to correct it?

Screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: While irrelevant to your problem, `lspci -v` must be run as root to view "Capabilities". `sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` will show you that information specific to audio.

Comment: try unmute spkr in ``alsamixer''

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out the problem using pacmd to determine if I was muted.  Turned out my Sound page opened to hide "System Sound," so I didn't see that it was muted.  How it got muted is another question